# Tethering android phone

Tags: wifi, configuration, internet

O.k. Due to my cable company mistakenly cutting the line for my internet connection I am stuck with using my phone tether to get internet access. They say it will be two to three weeks before they can fix it. A month is longer than I'm really willing to wait. my only other option is DSL and I don't have a phone line installed so I'm pretty sure the same issue would arise.

Getting the tether to my web browser is a cake walk, but the Software Center and Terminal programs will not access the internet. the Terminal adds  before my proxy address and the Software Center just doesn't work and I have no information as to why. I am simply looking to upgrade my system so all the people that will give me an opinion versus a solution I have time to ignore, but I would really like full access to my system and not just be able to access the internet via my web browser. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Linux version? which desktop?

Comment: I have found the desktop and version do not matter as I have tried several, but the current version I have installed is Linux Mint 21 (Vanessa) with the base desktop so I'm really not sure which desktop. I have tried Ubuntu 22.04, Ubuntu Mate, Debian 11 with all the desktops (Gnome, Xfce, etc.). Terminal and Software Managers never seem to work. Mint always pops up the update manager up, which makes life difficult to say the least and I'm tired of installing OS's to solve my problem, so I'm giving up and asking the question and dealing with the updater popping up for the moment.

Comment: Figured out that I'm using the Xfce desktop first off. I have gotten my issue sorted for the terminal at the very least using [This site](https://docs.nvidia.com/networking-ethernet-software/cumulus-linux-41/System-Configuration/Configuring-a-Global-Proxy/), I haven't even tried the Software Manager to say one way or the other,

Comment: have you tried restarting network manager service (after tethering)?  `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: I got it sorted. [using this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/713531/tethering-android-phone?noredirect=1#comment1351529_713531). The Software Manager was just to upgrade and not something that was a big deal other than that, but the solution on that site and it worked for me and I don't need the Software Manager is irrelevant after that as I have access to software installing.

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit tagging the title with "SOLVED".  If you have a solution, consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Note that a comment is not formally an answer, as the 1) are not peer reviewed, 2) can't be edited to add more information or correct wrong information, and 3) are often deleted.  Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: In all fairness, I added solved AFTER the comment as I didn't have a clue as to this information so now I know and appreciate the information and will take this into consideration in the future. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have been informed that a comment is not an answer... I solved my issue with the terminal, not sure about the Software Manager as I know how to install software with the Terminal making that piece irrelevant as I have access to the whole system. The solution I used [is located here](https://docs.nvidia.com/networking-ethernet-software/cumulus-linux-41/System-Configuration/Configuring-a-Global-Proxy/); this has only been tested with terminal by me. I have used it on several distributions in Virtualbox just to see if it worked in a virtual setting and it does...